# Why can't i detect a specific key press with pynput?

Tags: python, input, keyboard, pynput

I'm trying to make a program which runs in the background and detects a certain key being pressed to create a kind of hotkey, but for some reason I can't detect one specific key.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


def on_press(key):
    print(key)
    if str(key) == str('4'):
        print("test")

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Expected Output:

```
'4'
test
```

Actual Output:

```
'4'
```

Answer (score 0):

the following should help:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from pynput import keyboard


def on_press(key):
    print(key)
    #print(type(str(key)))
    if key.char == '4':
        print("test")

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

the output is following:

'f'
'g'
'j'
'd'
'y'
'j'
'k'
'e'
'd'
'r'
't'
'j'
'6'
'6'
'4'
test
'4'
test
'4'
test
'4'
test
'4'
test

I have used the following guide:

https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pynput/latest/pynput.pdf